# SharePoint External Sharing: Enabled in Admin Center, but not possible anyway

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, sharepoint-admin-center

in our SharePoint-Online tenant, external sharing isn't possible anymore from one day to another.

No one changed something in the admin settings and the settings should be set correctly:
[image: sharePoint sharing admin settings]

The enduser sharing dialogue looks like this since a few days:

[image: enduser sharing dialogue with message "your admin blocked it"]

External sharing isn't disabled on sharePoint site collection level, it's not possible on all sharePoint site collections: team sites and communication sites.

Has someone experienced something similar? Was there an update from microsoft who could have something to do with this?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First have a try to use powershell to set sharing ability. If this works for a certain site, you can apply this for all the site collections in your tenant

```
connect-sposervice -url https://<domain>-admin.sharepoint.com -cred(get-credential)
set-sposite -identity <siteURl> -SharingCapability ExternalUserAndGuestSharing
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is the same Setting as Akshay proposed in the GUI?

Comment: @ediordna, Yes, so you can try either and have a check. PowerShell takes in effect in seconds so i usually take this way.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this from SharePoint admin center.

Navigate to SPO Admin Center >>  Active sites >> select site from list of active site

On top bar you will see Sharing command click that.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I need to check this with a colleague, who has writing admin Rights. :D
In my admin Center it looks a bit different but indeed the Setting is on "only persons in your organisation". I recognized, that there is a quite similar Setting in: Microsoft 365 admin center -> ressources -> Websites. Has the setting there the same effect?
Still the Question is open who this could change on itself from one day to another. A few days ago external sharing was possible on all our SharePoint sitepages.

Comment: I am not very sure but this MAY BE impact of the latest feature released from Microsoft regarding time bound external access. You may find details in Message center. I am hearing this from lot of other users as well

Comment: Do you mean this Roadmap-Item: https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=43797 ?

Comment: no not the road map, the message center under tab in your Admin center.

Comment: yes, I came from the message Center notification, the Roadmap-item was linked there. I couldn't link the message Center notificiation (becaus it's only accessible in own Admin Center, so I linked the associated Roadmap-Item.